# What is the relation between the matrix of a bounded linear operator and that of its adjoint?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite-dimensional normed spaces, both real or both complex, and let $\dim X = n$ and $\dim Y = m$.

Let $E \colon= ( e_1, \ldots, e_n )$ be an ordered basis for $X$, and let $F \colon= (f_1, \ldots, f_m)$ be an ordered basis for $Y$.

Let $T \colon X \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator, and let $T^\times \colon Y^\prime \to X^\prime$ be the adjoint operator for $T$, where $X^\prime$ and $Y^\prime$ denote the dual spaces (i.e. the normed spaces of all the bounded linear functionals) of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Then is $X^\prime$ not (isomorphic with ) the space $K^n$, where $K$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? And, is $Y^\prime$ not (isomorphic with) the space $K^m$?

I reckon the answer to each of these questions is in the affirmative. Is it?

Now let $A \colon= [ \alpha_{ij}]_{m \times n}$ and $B \colon= [ \beta_{ij}]_{n \times m}$ be the matrices of $T$ and $T^\times$, respectively, with respect to the ordered bases $E$ and $F$.

Then how are the matrices $A$ and $B$ related?

By definition, the operator $T^\times \colon Y^\prime \to X^\prime$ is defined as follows:

Let $g \in Y^\prime$. Then $T^\times g$ is defined to be the linear functional $f$ defined on $X$ as $$f(x) \colon= g ( T x) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in X.$$ That is, for each $g \in Y^\prime$, the image $T^\times g \in X^\prime$ such that $$\left( T^\times g \right) (x) \colon= g(T x) \ \mbox{ for each } \ x \in X.$$

For each $j=1, \ldots, n$, since $T e_j \in Y$, so $T e_j$  has a unique representation as a linear combination of the elements of $F$, viz., 
$$T e_j = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{ij} f_i,$$
where the $\alpha_{ij}$ are scalars.

And, similarly, for the matrix $B$, except that now we will have to use the correcponding bases of $K^m$ and $K^n$.

Am I making any sense?

Is this generalised question a valid one?

If not, then please answer this question with $X$ replaced by $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $Y$ replaced by $\mathbb{C}^m$.

In this special case, the respective dual spaces are of course $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^m$.

Am I right?

Comment: The answer to your fist question is affirmative. You referred to a "generalized question." Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the dual basis, the matrix representation of $T^+$ is given by the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map#Representation_as_a_matrix), $T^t$.